# Output to display with Rust bare metal

Tags: rust, operating-system, sdl, osdev, glium

I'm following along with the [Phil-Opp tutorials on creating an OS](https://os.phil-opp.com/), and I'm trying to figure out how to control my display/screen, after having successfully gotten VGA output to work. How does one control the display? I'm assuming you have to write a driver... or do you write to specific memory locations like VGA? Would a crate like SDL2, Glium, or something else work on 'bare-metal'?

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you want to know. What does "control my display" mean? Are you trying to print text on the screen, draw shapes, change the resolution or refresh rate, turn the monitor on or off, etc.

Comment: It may be better to contact the author of that blog directly. See [https://os.phil-opp.com/contact/](https://os.phil-opp.com/contact/).

Comment: @WesleyWiser draw shapes, other-than-VGA text, etc.

Comment: @nbro that's a good idea. I'll try it, but he doesn't have anything about drawing on the screen on the tutorials.

Comment: @BenGubler Perhaps start here? https://wiki.osdev.org/GUI

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in a 8bpp VGA graphics mode (such as Mode 0x13), you can write pixels directly to the screen by writing to memory addresses `0xA0000` to `0xB8000`.

Comment: How do you set the VGA graphics mode? Thanks!